# Suma de horas con milisegundos (Mysql)

Tags: mysql

Estoy trabajando con MySQL versión 8.0.21. Actualmente guardo en un campo los tiempos de una carrera con un VARCHAR tal que así: 20:44,31, indicando que son 20 minutos, 44 segundos y 31 centésimas. A la hora de mostrarlo no hay ningún problema, pero quiero que si tengo dos carreras que pertenecen a la misma prueba, se sumen (puede haber carrera el sábado y domingo, y el ganador sea el que menor tiempo tenga en la suma).

Por ejemplo:

```
clasificaciones   tiempo             
========          ========
usuario1          20:43,73 
usuario2          21:22,44
usuario1          20:36,71
```

Cuando quiero sumar los tiempos hago lo siguiente:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(sum(TIME_TO_SEC(clasificaciones.tiempo))) as tiempo 
FROM pruebas, posiciones, prueba_carrera, carreras, clasificaciones 
where clasificaciones.carrera_id=carreras.id and carreras.id=prueba_carrera.carrera_id and prueba_carrera.prueba_id=pruebas.id and pruebas.id=posiciones.prueba_id and posiciones.equipo_id=equipos.id and equipos.id=clasificaciones.equipo_id and pruebas.id=5112 
group by posiciones.puesto 
order by posiciones.puesto
```

Esto me funciona perfectamente para los minutos y segundos, devolviéndome 41:19:00 para el usuario 1, pero no consigo que me funcione para las centésimas. He puesto punto en vez de coma en las horas, he probado a poner un tipo nuevo, el TIME, pero de todas maneras no me sale el cálculo bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que no pretendes cambiar los valores y deben quedarse tal como estan, mi anterior respuesta no es válida del todo.

Para solucionar tu problemática puedes usar `CONCAT()` para agregar el formato adecuado a tu consulta, y tambien usa `MICROSECONDS` para sumar correctamente los microsegundos, de este modo:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(sum(TIME_TO_SEC(CONCAT('00:',clasificaciones.tiempo))) + sum(microsecond(CONCAT('00:',clasificaciones.tiempo))/1000000)) as tiempo
FROM pruebas, posiciones, prueba_carrera, carreras, clasificaciones 
where clasificaciones.carrera_id=carreras.id and carreras.id=prueba_carrera.carrera_id and prueba_carrera.prueba_id=pruebas.id and pruebas.id=posiciones.prueba_id and posiciones.equipo_id=equipos.id and equipos.id=clasificaciones.equipo_id and pruebas.id=5112 
group by posiciones.puesto 
order by posiciones.puesto
```

Hay que decir que incialmente lo estaba probando en MariaDB 10, y resulta que hay diferencias en la función `TIME_TO_SEC` entre ambos motores de base de datos, pues MariaDB sí que tiene en cuenta los microsegundos, pudiendo ser su consulta un poco más corta, así:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(sum(TIME_TO_SEC(CONCAT('00:',clasificaciones.tiempo)))) as tiempo 
FROM pruebas, posiciones, prueba_carrera, carreras, clasificaciones 
where clasificaciones.carrera_id=carreras.id and carreras.id=prueba_carrera.carrera_id and prueba_carrera.prueba_id=pruebas.id and pruebas.id=posiciones.prueba_id and posiciones.equipo_id=equipos.id and equipos.id=clasificaciones.equipo_id and pruebas.id=5112 
group by posiciones.puesto 
order by posiciones.puesto
```

No me parece lo más idóneo pues con eso fuerzas que esos valores nunca puedan llegar a la hora, pero quizas sea suficiente en tu caso concreto.

Comment: Lo extraño aquí es que tú puedas obtener los decimales. En el momento que hago "sum(TIME_TO_SEC(clasificaciones.tiempo))" ya los pierde, por eso te preguntaba si haces algo diferente. Me devuelve un resultado de 148740 para usuario 1, que son exactamente 41:19 minutos, perdiendo los decimales, porque TIME_TO_SEC pasa una cantidad a segundos, no a microsegundos. El tipo de dato que has puesto es VARCHAR, ¿no? ¿Qué tamaño? Gracias.

Comment: Prueba esta: `SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(sum(TIME_TO_SEC(CONCAT('00:',clasificaciones.tiempo))) + sum(microsecond(CONCAT('00:',clasificaciones.tiempo))/1000000)) as tiempo FROM clasificaciones where clasificaciones.usuario="usuario1"` . Yo lo estaba haciendo en MariaDB 10, pero ahora lo acabo de probar en MySQL 8 y me da esto como resultado: `00:41:20.4400`

Comment: @AngelO Acabo de modificar la respuesta, ya me diras si ahora si. Perdona, no pensé en ningún momento que hubiera esa diferencia en la suma de microsegundos entre MariaDB 10 y MySQL 8 al convertirlo con TIME_TO_SEC

Comment: sí, ahí estaba el problema, en el microsecond, ya decía yo que no tenía mucho sentido que te saliese tan rápido. Eso lo hace perfectamente, muchas gracias.

Comment: @AngelO: Si esta respuesta "finalmente" soluciona tu caso :-)  por favor márcala como aceptada para que la comunidad lo pueda ver y no quede abierta eternamente. Gracias

Comment: Para formatear el tiempo utilizo time_format(XXX, '%H:%i:%s.%f'), pero el problema es que me muestra 00:41:20.440000, en vez de 00:41:20.44, ¿cómo puedo poner únicamente dos dígitos?

Comment: @AngelO Mira a ver si esto te ayuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48986371/get-milliseconds-with-date-format-in-mysql

Comment: @AngelO: Es decir, usa `SUBSTRING`. Aquí tienes unos ejemplos: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr  (de todos modos, si tienes problemas con eso, pon una nueva pregunta aqui, no sea que vayamos encadenando cosas en esta y luego los demas no lo sepan encontrar)

Comment: Perfecto, no había pensado en tratarlo como un string, me funciona genial, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

La fórmula parece correcta.

Prueba a cambiar los valores de la columna `tiempo` a este formato:

```
00:20:43.73
```

Donde:

- **00**: Son las horas
- **20**: Son los minutos
- **43**: Son los segundos
- **73**: Son los microsegundos

A mi me ha funcionado la suma creando una mínima versión de tu tabla con las dos columnas, y después de ver que si intentaba hacer la suma de `usuario2` me devolvia este formato erroneamente:

```
21:22:00.000000
```

Ante lo cual he deducido que necesitas el formato que acabo de poner más arriba. Lo he puesto en todos los registros y efectivamente me ha sumado correctamente `usuario1` dándome como resultado:

```
00:41:20.440000
```

Prueba y ya diras. Si mi respuesta cumple con tu propósito y la ves acertada, por favor, acéptala para que la comunidad lo sepa.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Como comentaba en la parte inferior, he probado con el punto en vez de la coma, y utilizando un formato TIME para que tenga el formato 00:00:00.000, pero así todo no me funciona.

Comment: Si utilizo TIME, introduzco los valores 00:20:43.73, 00:21:22.44 y 00:20:36.71, y en la consulta pongo únicamente SUM(clasificaciones.tiempo) entonces el resultado que me devuelve es 4080.46, vamos que suma las cifras por separado.

Comment: Acabo de agregar otra respuesta, pruebala y dime si esa te vale ahora.

Comment: De todos modos, si has cambiado lo valores correctamente a lo indicado en esta respuesta, usando tu consulta inicial deberia funcionarte bien.

Comment: Pero mi problema no es que muestre el formato de las horas, sino los milisegundos, que no me aparecen cuando tengo un VARCHAR. Cuando utilizo TIME me aparecen, pero al sobrepasar los 99 no suman uno a los segundos. ¿Cómo has conseguido en tu ejemplo que te aparezca 00:41:20.440000? Gracias.

Comment: Primero cambiando las comas por puntos en los valores, es decir, de `20:43,73` a `20:43.73`, y luego ejecutando una consulta simple con los datos que has dado asi: `SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(sum(TIME_TO_SEC(CONCAT('00:',clasificaciones.tiempo)))) as tiempo FROM clasificaciones where clasificaciones.usuario="usuario1"; 
`